# Sort an object array by euclidean distance

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sorte an object array by distance. Each object has a `x` and `y` coordinate and I want to sort the array so I have the next index is the closest point to `index - 1`

To do that, I created the following functions:

```
function compare(a, b) {
        dist_yy = (b.bounds.y) - (a.bounds.y);
        dist_xx = (b.bounds.x) - (a.bounds.x);
        dist = Math.sqrt(dist_yy*dist_yy + dist_xx*dist_xx); 
        console.log("distance " + dist)
        return dist;
    }

function sort_overlays(currOverlays) {
        sorted_overlays = currOverlays.sort(compare);
        currOverlays.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element);
        });

    return sort_overlays;        
}
```

However, it does not seem to work, since I was inspecting the final array (with 700+ points) and some look out of order.

Am I applying the `compare` function correctly?

kind regards

Comment: please add a (small) example and the wanted sort result.

Comment: Create a test case so that we can work this on a fiddle, provide an array of example objects with data etc etc..

Comment: note that if we consider elems of your array as node, we may want to select a path going through all the nodes, and greedily selecting the closest (not already visited) node as follower will not lead to an optimal path (in sense of length). see tsp, 2-opt and such. This may not be relevant to the question (but question is unclear regarding the "sorting" of the array)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not applying your compare function appropriately. A comparer function f(a,b) is meant to return:

- A negative number:  sort a to an index lower than b
- Zero: don't sort
- A positive number: sort a to an index higher than b

You are returning a distance, which is meaningless from a comparer perspective.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: you miss the point, that sorting a list of points is not possible, at leats if you look at three point, in which order do you want them to sort, even if the distance is ascending, but you can not have a real starting pont, without mention it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I appreciate that but regardless of being possible or not (I don't know, it's another problem) the function he is passing into the sort is not appropriate.